# opening notofication from gcmIntentClass to a fragment class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, google-cloud-messaging

I am receiving a notification from `GCM` ... in my GcmIntentService class I did this.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, 
    HomeActivity.class);
```

when I tap notification I want it to open a `Fragment` ..... I have my `Fragments` in HomeActivity.class from which I want to open Message `Fragment`.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this,
 HomeActivity.class );
                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
             mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameter with `Intent` like this

`notificationIntent.putExtra("fragment", 1);`

Where  1 is your fragment index and inside your `HomeActivity` you can use this

`int id=getIntent().getIntExtra("fragment", 0);
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);`

Comment: it takes me to the fragment tab but the fragment does'nt load.

Comment: @delive Can you share your code. So that I can help you.